# Why did Old French borrow "praemissa" for "premise"?

Tags: étymologie

It feels weird to think of premises as being "sent ahead". It makes more sense to think of premises as being put down, like in the etymology of the English *thesis* or French *thèse* quoted below.

> #### premise [14]

> *Premise* comes via Old French
> *premisse* from medieval Latin *praemissa*, a noun
> use of the past participle of Latin *praemittere*
> ‘send ahead’. This was a compound verb formed
> from the prefix *prae-* ‘before’ and *mittere* ‘send’
> (source of English *admit, commit, mission,
> transmit*, etc). It first entered English as a
> technical term in logic, in which its underlying
> meaning is of a proposition ‘set before’
> someone. But it was also used in the plural as a
> legal term, meaning ‘matters stated previously’.
> In a conveyance or will, such ‘matters’ were
> often houses or other buildings referred to
> specifically at the beginning of the document,
> and so the term *premises* came to denote such
> buildings.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto, p 392 Right column.

> #### thesis [14]

> Greek *thésis* meant literally a
> ‘placing’ or ‘laying down’ (it was derived from
> the verb *tithénai* ‘put, place’, which also gave
> English *apothecary*). It evolved metaphorically
> to ‘proposition’, and passed in this sense via late
> Latin *thesis* into English.

Op cit, p 504 Left column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old French didn't "borrow" from Latin, Latin evolved to what became Old French (among other languages.)

Anyway, there is no problem with ***premisse*** etymology being "**sent ahead**".

The *premisses* are the propositions "sent" ahead, i.e. transmitted, expressed first while the *conclusion* is what is expressed next.

Comment: Question bête : Premisse est-il bien un évolution depuis le latin via l'ancien français et non une formation savante directe depuis le latin comme on en a eu beaucoup depuis le XVIIe siècle ?

Comment: @XouDo Il était présent en ancien français. On trouve *prémisses* dans un texte de 1350 environ de [Gilles le Muisit](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_Le_Muisit) : *Ensi li manda Dieu et li fist ches prémisses* Poésies, p 358.